# Regular expressions: Match domains with obfuscated separators

Tags: regex

I have this regular expresion that was handed down to me, it matches nice domains such us:
`google.com`, `google.com.us`, etc. In Python:

```
     """([\d\w.][-\d\w.]{0,253}[\d\w.]+\.)+
        (AC|AD|AE|AERO|AF|AG|AI|AL|AM|AN|AO|AQ|AR|ARPA|
         AS|ASIA|AT|AU|AW|AX|AZ|BA|BB|BD|BE|BF|BG|BH|BI|
         BIZ|BJ|BM|BN|BO|BR|BS|BT|BV|BW|BY|BZ|CA|CAT|CC|
         CD|CF|CG|CH|CI|CK|CL|CM|CN|CO|COM|COOP|CR|CU|CV|CX|
         CY|CZ|DE|DJ|DK|DM|DO|DZ|EC|EDU|EE|EG|ER|ES|ET|EU|
         FI|FJ|FK|FM|FO|FR|GA|GB|GD|GE|GF|GG|GH|GI|GL|GM|
         GN|GOV|GP|GQ|GR|GS|GT|GU|GW|GY|HK|HM|HN|HR|HT|HU|
         ID|IE|IL|IM|INFO|INT|IO|IQ|IR|IS|IT|JE|JM|JO|JOBS|
         JP|KE|KG|KH|KI|KM|KN|KP|KR|KW|KY|KZ|LA|LB|LC|LI|LK|
         LR|LS|LT|LU|LV|LY|MA|MC|MD|ME|MG|MH|MIL|MK|ML|MM|
         MN|MO|MOBI|MP|MQ|MR|MS|MT|MU|MUSEUM|MV|MW|MX|MY|MZ|
         NA|NAME|NC|NET|NF|NG|NI|NL|NO|NP|NR|NU|NZ|OM|ORG|
         PA|PE|PF|PG|PH|PK|PL|PM|PN|PR|PRO|PS|PT|PW|PY|QA|
         RE|RO|RS|RU|RW|SA|SB|SC|SD|SE|SG|SH|SI|SJ|SK|SL|SM|
         SN|SO|SR|ST|SU|SV|SY|SZ|TC|TD|TEL|TF|TG|TH|TJ|TK|
         TL|TM|TN|TO|TP|TR|TRAVEL|TT|TV|TW|TZ|UA|UG|UK|US|
         UY|UZ|VA|VC|VE|VG|VI|VN|VU|WF|WS|XN|XN|XN|XN|XN|
         XN|XN|XN|XN|XN|XN|YE|YT|YU|ZA|ZM|ZW)"""
```

Now, sometimes domains are 'obfuscated' like: `google<.>com`, `google[.]com[.]us`, note the weird separators.
I'm not very good with regular expressions, I would like to know whether there is way to extend this re so it matches domains with these separators.

Thanks

Comment: Those obfuscated domains aren't entirely valid domains - they generally follow the scheme of somename.somesite.sometld.  Is the assumption valid that a regex would ignore those?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is not a good idea to put com co org, etc. in your regex. It should be general.
You could use the following regex as an alternative:

```
(((https?)|(ftp)):\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)(\[\.\]|<\.>|\.)([a-z\.]{2,8})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?
```

it would match google.com, google[.]com and google<.>com as well.

Still if you want to use your regex, use the following:

```
([\d\w.][-\d\w.]{0,253}[\d\w.]+(\[\.\]|<\.>|\.))+(AC|AD|AE|AERO|AF|AG|AI|AL|AM|AN|AO|AQ|AR|ARPA|AS|ASIA|AT|AU|AW|AX|AZ|BA|BB|BD|BE|BF|BG|BH|BI|BIZ|BJ|BM|BN|BO|BR|BS|BT|BV|BW|BY|BZ|CA|CAT|CC|CD|CF|CG|CH|CI|CK|CL|CM|CN|CO|COM|COOP|CR|CU|CV|CX|CY|CZ|DE|DJ|DK|DM|DO|DZ|EC|EDU|EE|EG|ER|ES|ET|EU|FI|FJ|FK|FM|FO|FR|GA|GB|GD|GE|GF|GG|GH|GI|GL|GM|GN|GOV|GP|GQ|GR|GS|GT|GU|GW|GY|HK|HM|HN|HR|HT|HU|ID|IE|IL|IM|INFO|INT|IO|IQ|IR|IS|IT|JE|JM|JO|JOBS|JP|KE|KG|KH|KI|KM|KN|KP|KR|KW|KY|KZ|LA|LB|LC|LI|LK|LR|LS|LT|LU|LV|LY|MA|MC|MD|ME|MG|MH|MIL|MK|ML|MM|MN|MO|MOBI|MP|MQ|MR|MS|MT|MU|MUSEUM|MV|MW|MX|MY|MZ|NA|NAME|NC|NET|NF|NG|NI|NL|NO|NP|NR|NU|NZ|OM|ORG|PA|PE|PF|PG|PH|PK|PL|PM|PN|PR|PRO|PS|PT|PW|PY|QA|RE|RO|RS|RU|RW|SA|SB|SC|SD|SE|SG|SH|SI|SJ|SK|SL|SM|SN|SO|SR|ST|SU|SV|SY|SZ|TC|TD|TEL|TF|TG|TH|TJ|TK|TL|TM|TN|TO|TP|TR|TRAVEL|TT|TV|TW|TZ|UA|UG|UK|US|UY|UZ|VA|VC|VE|VG|VI|VN|VU|WF|WS|XN|XN|XN|XN|XN|XN|XN|XN|XN|XN|XN|YE|YT|YU|ZA|ZM|ZW)
```

If you need any description, do let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The second expression seems to work fine for domains separated by `.`, but those using `<.>` and `[.]` are not matching the first part of the domain: `"google.com.co" -> [('google.com.', '.', 'co')]`, `"google<.>com<.>co" -> [('com<.>', '<.>', 'co')].`